# Dismantling Old Pilot Light Switch

Tags: pilot-light

[image]I have an old pilot light switch on my fireplace wall. Over the years our council house has many joblot repairs. One of which is our gas fire being replaced by an electric fire & the gas boiler in the cupboard behind the fire being moved to a bedroom cupboard so I assume the pilot light no longer works.
During decorating I decided to take out the switch but on removing the cover I found lots of connected wires embedded deep in the wall. I'm 90% sure its safe to remove because years ago the council installed a new thermostat without taking the old one out, but the lights on it wouldn't work, so I assumed it was obsolete & removed it myself.
The pilot light switch has no light to indicate it's obsolete, it may still be connected to something deep in the walls & of course, its electrical so I don't wanna mess with it without being sure. Any advice?

Comment: It's common for a box that contains a switch to also be a junction point for other wires.  Is that the point of your question?  You can remove the switch, but the other wires should probably not be touched unless you know exactly what each one does.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring situation?